# How can I auto refresh Google Sheets data source in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I created a project in Data Studio connected to Google Sheets in Google Drive.

I need to update the data on the sheet periodically. I import the data from another Excel sheet but after doing this, I have to update the connection of the data sources in Data Studio.

Is there any way to update the Excel sheets without editing the connections?

Answer (score 1):

You can Update the excel sheets without editing the connections. you can force Data Studio to update the report cache by clicking Refresh [image] in the righthand side of the report header.

[image]

For more info check this link: https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7083608

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the "Enable Cache" under Report Settings (Files > Report Settings):

[image: Data Studio - Cache Control]

Here is a description on how Data Studio caches data: [Manage data freshness](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020039?ref_topic=6309857)

Comment: Hi, i uncheck the "Enable cache" but the problem persists. I import data in google sheet. After i go to data studio and i need to reconnect excel data source